# Is there a way to set the MaxResults for a Google Cloud Vision query to unlimited?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I've set it to 9999 for now but I could've sworn I saw somewhere that you can set it to unlimited somehow!

If not, what is the highest number you can set it to?

My request is looking like this:

```
        "requests":[{
            "image": {
                "content": base64String
            },
            "features": [
                {"type":"TEXT_DETECTION","maxResults":9999}, 
                {"type":"LABEL_DETECTION","maxResults":10},
                ],
            "imageContext": {
                "languageHints": [
                    "de",
                    "en"
                ]
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Until now there is no option like using a CONSTANT instead `int32` for fetching all outputs. You can use the maximum value of TYPE_INT32 i.e 2147483647 for this property.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like what I was looking for. You should write it as an answer, so I can accept it!

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, I added above as an answer please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now there is no option like using a CONSTANT instead int32 for fetching all outputs. You can use the maximum value of TYPE_INT32 i.e 2147483647 for this property(maxResults).

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a higher maxResults if you like, though it doesn't mean that there will actually be that many results since it's just a max.

Also note that maxResults doesn't apply to all features (like TEXT_DETECTION in your case): https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature

Comment: Good to know that it isn't even supported by text detection, that kind of makes my question superfluous. For future reference though: Is there a way to set it to the maximum number possible and not just any number? Like a constant you can use?